# How do I remove specific URL from user input?

Tags: php

I want remove some URL from user input.

Example user input

```
$input = 'http://www.yahoo.com/';
$input = 'http://yahoo.com/';
$input = 'www.yahoo.com';
$input = 'yahoo.com';
$input = 'http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index;_ylt=AhiI2Ax0jmujpU01wK7W4cLj1KIX;_ylv=3?qid=20110224130854AA9LGdy';
$input = '<a href="http://yahoo.com">yahoo</a>';
$input = '<a href="http://yahoo.com">http://yahoo.com</a>';
$input = 'I love <a href="http://yahoo.com">http://yahoo.com</a>';

output I love
```

Any domain with `yahoo.com` I want remove the output or return empty result. Maybe more than one domain. Let me know.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. could you reword your question?

Comment: If I understood it correctly you want empty string to result from this input. Is that right?

Comment: Hmmm.. sorry guys. I don't know how to describe my question. Dagon was give an example what I want it :)

Comment: @Voooza Yes, I want empty string to the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$domains = array('yahoo.com', 'other-domain.org');
$domainsrgx = implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $domains));

$filtered_userinput = preg_replace('#(^|\s+)(https?://)?([^/\s]*\.)?('.$domainsrgx.')(/[^\s]*)?(?=(\s|$))#is', '', $userinput);
```

This should remove everything from your example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data=str_replace('yahoo.com','',$data);
```

you can use an array to replace\remove multiple domains

```
$remove=array('yahoo.com','google.com');
$data=str_replace($remove,'',$data);
```

Comment: Thanks but it will remove `yahoo.com` only.

Comment: you can add the variations to the array, or use preg_replace()

Answer (score 0):

Ok. You can do

```
$rows = split("[\n|\r]", $input);
$output = "";
foreach($rows as $row){
     if(strpos($row,"yahoo.com")){
          continue;
     }else{
          $output = $row."\n";
     }
}
```

I hope I'm not missing anything.